# Apache Camel with Spring Boot - Zip process

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying to process a zip file with Apache Camel.
After making a call, I get a zip file and try to prepare the next call with this zip file as body.
The call requires a form data with one name and zip file as value.
I handle in this way:

```
process(e ->{
                    Object zip = e.getIn().getBody();                        
                    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                    body.add("file",zip);
                    e.getIn().setBody(body);
                })
```

But I receive the exception:

```
org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value {file=[[B@2b02c691]}
```

Any Ideas?

Cheers!

I tried to get the response in byte[] but it still dose not work.

Comment: You need to share more of your code. The error message indicates that your next step in the route is expecting something it can convert to an inputstream. I'm guessing this is your unzip step.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy said, the error says Camel is expecting (further in the process) a body of type `InputStream`, whilst you are obviously preparing a body of type `MultiValueMap` (BTW: why use a map if you have a **single** object to handle ??)

I do not know what is the concrete type of your 'zip' object, but (if needed) you may have to replace current body with its inputstream equivalent:

```
process(e ->{
   // Print concrete type
   Object zip = e.getMessage().getBody(); 
   System.out.println("Type is " + zip.getClass() );
   // Convert body
   InputStream is = e.getMessage().getBody(InputStream.class); 
   // Replace body                       
   e.getMessage().setBody(is);
})
```

Comment: I result get directly the byte[] from properties, I also changed the map with MultipartEntityBuilder that provides method for ad binary body to a request :D